# How to force CKEditor to use HTML Numbers instead of special Characters

Tags: ckeditor, special-characters, html-entities, html-encode

How can I force CKEditor to automatically convert special Characters to HTML Numbers?

For example when I write `6%` in the editor  and then look at the source code I get `<p>6%</p>` but what I want to get in the source is `<p>6&#37;</p>`

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this option [`config.entities`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities) and all other `entities_*` options. Using them, you can configure editor to produce entities only for `nbsp`, `gt`, `lt` and `amp`. It is also possible to switch that off (check [`config.basicEntities`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-basicEntities)), but it may causes issues as noted in docs.

Comment: what option should I use only to fix the percentage problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.config.entities_additional = '#36,#37'; //$,%
```

Please, check too:

```
CKEDITOR.config.entities_processNumerical = 'force';
```